# Is furring strip needed with a vertical Shiplap wall when installed over blocking in wall frame?

Tags: walls, studs, paneling

My task is to install a vertical Shiplap wall. I removed the drywall down to the exposed stud wall. I’ve then added blocking between the studs every 24” from floor to ceiling. I’ll put new drywall over the studs to meet the fire code. I’ll then have a steady horizontal backing to nail into when installing my paneling vertically.

Every tutorial I read says to attach furring strips to the drywall for your panels to attach to. But I assume this is because the wall wouldn’t have blocking that you’d nail into when installing the paneling? I’m starting to think adding furring strips directly over the stud blocking for the paneling to attach to would be overkill.

The added benefit of no furring strip in my example is I could add adhesive to the backs of the panels which will sit flush against the drywall in addition to the nails on the blocking for extra support. I wouldn’t be able to do this if I had an additional 1” furring strip on the drywall.

Comment: Vertical shiplap = the boards running vertically?  If you 've got continuous blocking, I don't see a need for furring strips, as long as you're confident of hitting the blocking.

Comment: @Huesmann answers go down there. You'll get my vote when you do.